# How do you use the void pointer in C?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

Here are a couple of function declarations that I'm having trouble understanding how to complete. I've scanned the web to see what a void pointer is, and I understand that it must be cast to something to be useful (because it just points to some memory block), but I don't see how that helps in completing these declarations.

```
/* type of comparison function that specifies a unique order.
   Returns 1 if pointer1 should come before,
   0 if equal to, or -1 if after pointer2. */
typedef int (*compare_function) (const void* pointer1, const void* pointer2);

/* get the data object */
void* get_obj(const void* item_pointer);
```

There are more functions like this, but I think if I understand how to do these two I should be in good shape. For example, for the second function, how do we cast the item_pointer to anything appropriate that should be returned?

Comment: Good question, but too broad.

Comment: Are you the one that has to implement get_obj? If yes, then it greatly depends on what item_pointer is supposed to be.

Comment: The first one is a function pointer. You most likely have to define a function with this signature. You know what types `pointer1` and `pointer2` will be so you can typecast those appropriately.

Comment: Fiddling Bits is right, you would have to use `compare_function` as a operand in a function. . . e.g. `compFunc(compare_function* cFunc);`

Comment: Void pointers are most useful for functions that don't need to de-reference them but need to pass them nonetheless. A perfect example is `pthread_create()` and family. This function will accept a pointer to a function and a void pointer for the parameter to the function. This pthread_create() itself doesn't care what the parameter for the function is, thus the void pointer will serve as a template so to speak. The called function, is then responsible for knowing what type the void pointer should be.

Comment: I was about to comment on another question of yours that you just deleted: “Please take the time to understand what questions are and aren't welcome here before asking your other questions about graphics for game development. Vague, open-ended, chatty questions are considered off-topic here even if they are about programming.”

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`void *` usually means that you are only interested in the address of the data regardless of its type, some of the reasons:

- the internal representation of the data this `void *` pointing to is hidden, you are not supposed to access the data directly, [*information hiding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding), your function 2 is properly an example of this case.
- the type is known by some function in the call chain, like with `qsort` and most functions that pass arguments to other functions.
- the type is not required because the data the pointer is pointing to will be handled as different type, like with `memcpy` which may handle the data as bytes, `unsigned char *`.

Answer (score 1):

Sorting in C with quicksort uses void pointers so that we can sort any data in arrays.  The sort function must return -1, +1, or 0 if the parameter  b is before, after or the same as parameter a

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int sort_order( const void *, const void *);

int main(void)
{
  int i;
  char alfa[6] = { ’C’, ’E’, ’A’, ’D’, ’F’, ’B’ }; 
  qsort( (char*)alfa, 6, sizeof(char), sort_order); 
  for (i=0 ; i<5 ; i++)  // now in order?
     printf("\nchar %d = %c",i, alfa[i]);
  printf("\n");
  system("PAUSE");
  return 0;
}

int sort_order( const void* a, const void* b)
{
  if      ( *((char*)a) < *((char*)b) )     return -1 ;
  else if ( *((char*)a) > *((char*)b) )     return  1 ;
  else                                      return  0 ;
}
```

Then you can sort your own datatypes:

```
typedef struct {   float left;   float right;} ears;
typedef struct{  char name[13];  int weight;  ears eararea;} monkey;    

monkey* Index[4];

for(i=0;i<4;i++)   
    Index[i]= (monkey* )malloc(sizeof(monkey));     

qsort((void* ) Index, 4, sizeof(monkey* ), sort_order);

// Sorted by weight    
int sort_order( const void* a, const void* b) {   
    if((**((monkey** )a)).weight < (**((monkey** )b)).weight) return -1 ;   
    else if ((**((monkey** )a)).weight > (**((monkey** )b)).weight ) return  1 ;
    else return  0 ;
}
```

### Complete program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    float left;
    float right;
} ears;

typedef struct {
    char name[13];
    int weight;
    ears eararea;
} monkey;

int sort_monkeys( const void *, const void *);

int main(void)
{   monkey* monkeys[4];
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<4; i++) {
        monkeys[i]= (monkey* )malloc(sizeof(monkey));
        monkeys[i]->weight=i*10;
        if (i==2)
            monkeys[i]->weight=1;
    }
    for (i=0 ; i<4; i++)
        printf("\nchar %d = %i",i, monkeys[i]->weight);

    qsort((void* ) monkeys, 4, sizeof(monkey* ), sort_monkeys);

    for (i=0 ; i<4; i++)  // now in order?
        printf("\nmonkey %d = %i",i, monkeys[i]->weight);
    return 0;
}

// Sorted by weight
int sort_monkeys( const void* a, const void* b) {
    if((**((monkey** )a)).weight < (**((monkey** )b)).weight) return -1 ;
    else if ((**((monkey** )a)).weight > (**((monkey** )b)).weight ) return  1 ;
    else return  0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any pointer type may be assigned to a `void*`, this is useful in cases where a function does not need to know the type, or the type information is conveyed by other means.  This allows you to write just one function to deal with any pointer type rather than a separate function for each data type.

While you cannot dereference a `void*` you can cast it to any type and dereference it - the semantics of that - i.e. whether it is meaningful, depends on the code and is not enforced byte compiler.

Frequently a *generic* function is not interested in the content of some block of data, just its address and often its size.

As a simple example:

```
void memcopy( void* to, void* from, int length )
{
    char* source = (char*)from ;
    char* dest = (char*)to ;
    int i ;

    for( i = 0; i < lengt; i++ )
    {
        dest[i] = source[i] ;
    }
}

int main()
{
    typedef struct
    {
        int x ;
        int y ;

    } tItem

    tItem AllItems[256] = {0} ;
    tItem AllItemsCopy[256] ;

    memcopy( AllItemsCopy, AllItems, sizeof(AllItems) ) ;
}
```

See that `memcopy()` does not need to know what a `tItem` is in order to copy an array of them, it only needs to know the addresses and the size on the array in bytes.  It casts the `void*` pointer arguments to reinterpret the data as a `char` array to perform a byte-by-byte copy.  To do that it does not need to know the internal semantics of `tItem` or any other data object passed to it.